# Azure Devops pipeline build failure Failed to execute goal The artifact information is incomplete or not valid 'version' is missing

Tags: java, azure, devops, pipeline, nexus

We ( dev team ) are trying build the application in the azure enviroment, but we are receiving the following erro:

POM.XML in sequence

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9736202Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9737310Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9738503Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9739621Z [INFO] Total time: 0.382 s

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9740583Z [INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-26T19:02:43Z

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9742047Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9743721Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9745147Z [ERROR]   [0]  'version' is missing.

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9746030Z [ERROR]

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9747289Z [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9748009Z [ERROR]

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9749077Z [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9750293Z [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9751459Z [ERROR]

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9752307Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9753312Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9755256Z ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9757939Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9795280Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9806576Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '1'.

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9808790Z ##[debug]task result: Failed

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9812040Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]

> 2022-07-26T19:02:43.9815121Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload app JAR to Nexus

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.company.anything</groupId>
    <artifactId>company.anything</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>company.anything</name>
    <description>Used for something</description>
    <inceptionYear>2021</inceptionYear>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <organization>
        <name>My home</name>
    </organization>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
        <start-class>br.com.company.anything.Application</start-class>
        <spring.boot.version>2.5.6</spring.boot.version>
        <project.java.version>11</project.java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <mockito.version>3.9.0</mockito.version>
        <byte-buddy.version>1.11.22</byte-buddy.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.29</snakeyaml.version>
        <json-path.version>2.6.0</json-path.version>
        <jackson-databind-nullable>0.2.1</jackson-databind-nullable>
        <jakarta.xml.bind-api.version>3.0.1</jakarta.xml.bind-api.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.21.0</assertj-core.version>
        <jedis-clients.version>3.7.0</jedis-clients.version>
        <org.json.version>20220320</org.json.version>
        
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
        <swagger-annotations-version>1.5.22</swagger-annotations-version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>2.1.11</swagger-annotations.version>

        <!-- Compiler -->
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.resources.version>3.2.0</maven.resources.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit5.version>5.6.2</junit5.version>
        <embedded-redis.version>0.7.3</embedded-redis.version>

        <!--Sonar -->
        <sonar.maven.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar.maven.version>
        <sonar.exclusions>src/test/**/*,**/configuration/**,**/exception/**,**/domain/**,**/dto/**</sonar.exclusions> 
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>src/test/**/*,**/configuration/**,**/exception/**,**/domain/**,**/dto/**</sonar.coverage.exclusions> 
        <sonar.test.exclusions>src/test/**/*</sonar.test.exclusions>
        <woodstox-core.version>6.2.6</woodstox-core.version>
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>${byte-buddy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
            <version>${byte-buddy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${json-path.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${jedis-clients.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${embedded-redis.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>opin-srv-identificacao-cadastramento</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludedClasses>
                        <param>**.domain*</param>
                        <param>**.dto*</param>
                        <param>**.exception*</param>
                        <param>**.configuration*</param>
                        <param>**.external*</param>
                    </excludedClasses>
                    <outputFormats>
                        <outputFormat>xml</outputFormat>
                    </outputFormats>
                    <threads>4</threads>
                    <avoidCallsTo>
                        <avoidCallsTo>java.util.logging</avoidCallsTo>
                        <avoidCallsTo>org.apache.log4j</avoidCallsTo>
                        <avoidCallsTo>org.slf4j</avoidCallsTo>
                        <avoidCallsTo>org.apache.commons.logging</avoidCallsTo>
                    </avoidCallsTo>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/specification/company.anything.yaml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>br.com.company.anything.interfaceadapter.autogenerated.delegate</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>br.com.company.anything.interfaceadapter.autogenerated.domain</modelPackage>
                            <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</templateDirectory>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <basePackage>br.com.company.anything</basePackage>
                                <invokerPackage>br.com.company.anything</invokerPackage>
                                <configPackage>br.com.company.anything.external.configuration</configPackage>
                                <modelPackage>br.com.company.anything.interfaceadapter.autogenerated.domain</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>br.com.company.anything.interfaceadapter.autogenerated.delegate</apiPackage>
                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                    @lombok.Builder
                                    @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                                    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                                </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${woodstox-core.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <release>${project.java.version}</release>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <!-- Excludes integration tests from build execution -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*IntTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

We read a lot of question but no one until now fix the problem.
You can suggest any configuration tha we´ll check.

PS: Our team does not have access to the azure pipeline configuration to change anything, there are others projects running there, we need isolate the problem and to be sure that is not in our code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eclipse Spring Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZnk.png)

Hi all,

I resolved my problem configuring th end of line EOF
from CRLF to LF

I hope this help who faces this problem

see you